# What is the fastest way to move in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

So from what I can tell there are no mounts, and my only means of movement are either teleporting to waypoints and temples, or sprinting and gliding everywhere.  Since I'm aware that this has a China version, but I've never really played the Chinese version, are there mounts or accessories of any sort that make moving faster? I do know that upgrading the Shrines of the Seven increase my stamina, but that doesn't necessarily seem to make my character move any faster while gliding or sprinting, it just gives a longer duration. Are there are any sets that perhaps make movement faster? Or any food items that make me move faster?

Comment: I assume you mean other than teleporting to unlocked teleport destinations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Height matters**

A hidden mechanic not really explained but something you can experience is that *taller* characters move faster than *shorter* characters. This is clearly evident when you compare someone like Diluc to someone like Qiqi.  Bigger bodies mean the stride length is longer, so each "sprint" moves you further than shorties.  Males in general are taller than female counterparts -- this is true especially with the Male/Female Traveler.

**Theoretical Fastest Movement Speed**

For the theoretical fastest movement speed, we need:

- 2 Ameno users in our party
- 4 party members from Mondstadt
- 1 party member who uses a R5 4★ Catalyst "Wine & Song"
- (Optional) 1 party member with sprint stamina reduction passive

Thus, with a party setup of Sucrose, Venti, Razor/Kaeya, Any other Mondstandt member, we can achieve a 10% + (5% * 4) = 30% movement speed increase.

**Sources of Movement Speed Increase**

- Impetuous Winds (Elemental Resonance)

  - Requires 2 Anemo users in your party
  - Increases Movement Speed +10%
  - Decreases Stamina Consumption +15%
- Constellation Lvl 6 for Amber

  - Fiery Rain increases Amber's Movement SPD by 15% for 10s.
- 5 ★★★★★ Catalyst "Lost Prayer to the Sacred Winds"

  - Increases Movement Speed +10%
- 5 ★★★★★ Sword "Skyward Blade"

  - Using an Elemental Burst increases Movement SPD by 10% for 12s.
- 4 ★★★★ Bow "Prototype Crescent"

  - Aimed Shot hits on weak points increase Movement SPD by 10% for 10s.
- 3 ★★★ Sword "Skyrider Sword"

  - Using an Elemental Burst grants a 12/15/18/21/24% Movement SPD increase for 12s.
- 3 ★★★ Catalyst "Twin Nephrite"

  - Defeating an enemy increases Movement SPD by 12/14/16/18/20% for 15s.

Comment: Various stamina reducing and replenishing foods also worth bearing in mind.

Comment: There are more weapons that increase movement speed, for example "Twin Nephrite" and "Wine and Song" catalysts, see https://genshin.gg/weapons

Comment: @arghtype Thanks for that, I'll add them to the list

Comment: Can you give us Reference from that speed buff from every mondstadt member?

Comment: @JovylleBermudez I've removed it because I just realize it was outdated information using weapons that were only available in the closed beta.

Comment: you may want to add that Mona one-of-a-kind dash is actually faster than any other character so far... at least until Ayaka is released.

Comment: you should add to this Rosaria's passive talent as well as a source of movement speed

Answer (score 11):

**Bunny hopping** (constant jumping) is actually faster than regular sprinting. Source: this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/j9n6ag/the_best_sprint_method_and_the_best_character_for/) where author did all necessary testing, [direct video link](https://v.redd.it/emvnr9esjms51/HLSPlaylist.m3u8) from it.

Comment: Gah, I wish I could accept two answers at once.   Bunny hopping is indeed the fastest way to move about, but with movement speed increases bhopping can get you even further and faster.

Comment: FYI that direct video link only works on browsers with builtin HLS support so that excludes 90% of users

Answer (score 3):

With patch 1.1 and Diona, you can add another 10% move with her shield.  Make sure to hold for 5 vs 2.

Only need the first ascension.